# Cloud Spatial Exception : Azure Spatial Anchor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, azure-spatial-anchors

I wanted to work on Azure Spatial Anchor. I am following the [Quickstart: Create a Unity Android app with Azure Spatial Anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-android#create-a-spatial-anchors-resource).

I have built the Android app successfully and installed it.
Now, while trying to save the anchor to the cloud it is throwing a
"Cloud Spatial Exception".

What should I do to fix this?

The complete log is as follows for reference

```
<"Log
Scene AzureSpatialAnchorsDemoLauncher is loaded

Warning
The referenced script (UnityEngine.XR.WSA.SpatialMappingCollider) on this Behaviour is missing!

Warning
The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'HoloLensCamera') is missing!

Error
A scripted object (probably UnityEngine.XR.WSA.SpatialMappingCollider?) has a different serialization layout when loading. (Read 32 bytes but expected 100 bytes)
Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?

Log
Scene AzureSpatialAnchorsBasicDemo is loaded

Log
>>Azure Spatial Anchors Demo Script Start

Log
3

Log
Azure Spatial Anchors Demo script started

Log
State from DemoStepCreateSession to DemoStepConfigSession

Log
State from DemoStepConfigSession to DemoStepStartSession

Log
State from DemoStepStartSession to DemoStepCreateLocalAnchor

Log
State from DemoStepCreateLocalAnchor to DemoStepSaveCloudAnchor

Log
State from DemoStepSaveCloudAnchor to DemoStepSavingCloudAnchor

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '8bba1602-5798-8544-a21b-bef8c8499f0f'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f1bc880d-0387-0e44-b1d2-fb4b362a0ba0'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '27351428-b364-9742-94b4-290bf520d77b'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '4376bf3c-e542-1649-86a1-e16897b50e49'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f8ccae45-9803-9644-bab2-2227bc353da3'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'a5ba8248-be82-4346-8cf6-2bf9f07f2b97'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'cf740163-185c-a14b-a383-9beec3d2f47b'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'd940dc71-04c4-6a45-8c65-97af01b501a0'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'b172bc7d-73df-7642-a742-38a6ecf804c5'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '7ca2aaac-3f3d-f846-9cbf-764c811e484d'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '5fc5e1b0-0df9-6b47-84c8-63b110d4d9ba'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '328449c0-8806-fd47-88a3-ad13a15254ea'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'b9ba57c8-813a-2b48-8a13-1642ca9ceda4'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'ffbccad0-3553-3a48-9ce3-90760d2f98ec'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'b88c88d7-418b-3247-8de7-c8b72898dcbe'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '7bfb0cdd-ba72-f844-8415-00a5907b0ad8'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '398150df-d753-6147-a464-0b55cf7b1183'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'd23060e1-8643-ab4e-883b-e5b76271e9b2'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '060f16fd-e36e-f541-bec2-b79638af17d0'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] World Anchor is no longer Locatable....so we have to ignore this frame as we don't know it's pose. We also deleted 19 key-frames that are no longer locatable.

Log
RestClient::CreateNeighborhoodAnchorAndSpatialAnchorAsync - HTTP Response Status Code: 500. ReqCV: uUdXVl7PSnaYAriUIuDeQA. RespCV: OYomOsnSPUWZnNinzWU4wQ.0.

Log
CreateNeighborhoodAnchorAndSpatialAnchor failed with HTTP error 500. ReqCV: uUdXVl7PSnaYAriUIuDeQA. ResCV: OYomOsnSPUWZnNinzWU4wQ.0. JSON Error: {"error":{"code":"Unexpected null server response","message":"Unexpected null server response"}}

Log
Service unavailable or unspecified error found

Exception
CloudSpatialException
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.NativeLibraryHelpers.CheckStatus (System.IntPtr handle, Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.status value) (at <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession+<>c__DisplayClass82_0.<CreateAnchorAsync>b__0 () (at <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession+<CreateAnchorAsync>d__82.MoveNext () (at <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.SpatialAnchorManager+<CreateAnchorAsync>d__45.MoveNext () (at <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Examples.DemoScriptBase+<SaveCurrentObjectAnchorToCloudAsync>d__41.MoveNext () (at <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Examples.DemoScriptBase:OnSaveCloudAnchorFailed(Exception)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Examples.AzureSpatialAnchorsBasicDemoScript:OnSaveCloudAnchorFailed(Exception)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Examples.<SaveCurrentObjectAnchorToCloudAsync>d__41:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:SetException(Exception)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.<CreateAnchorAsync>d__45:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:SetException(Exception)
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.<CreateAnchorAsync>d__82:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks()

Log
Failed to save anchor Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialException
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.NativeLibraryHelpers.CheckStatus (System.IntPtr handle, Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.status value) [0x00180] in <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession+<>c__DisplayClass82_0.<CreateAnchorAsync>b__0 () [0x00035] in <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession+<CreateAnchorAsync>d__82.MoveNext () [0x00082] in <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.SpatialAnchorManager+<CreateAnchorAsync>d__45.MoveNext () [0x000fe] in <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Examples.DemoScriptBase+<SaveCurrentObjectAnchorToCloudAsync>d__41.MoveNext () [0x00187] in <7af96a2fb3f6418eb7043e85c2f0a2a4>:0 

Log
Saving logs to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.examples.unity.helloar/files/logs.txt

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'a9119e04-1ddb-f148-b2dd-261d765114d7'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'fcd00510-c1bb-4045-9797-d0657fc944d6'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '90039313-12ae-a14f-8725-df752f12aaac'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '52b02f15-6aeb-0c41-b452-8d5e7bb8cf24'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '15d5bf16-6073-b14f-8df9-3e8bd20d5521'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'fb24f320-53b1-7f44-8277-21da004b370e'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '3f03ac24-a6a1-3a42-8f0d-d2fb1b2c5261'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'eb79fb24-7b46-1947-b927-1be2879a2d4e'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'a3223226-192b-944e-9767-5f1f3e601825'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f3313727-7490-0f44-9555-83e8205a4366'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'e8f06a38-9416-ea41-8716-59c48bbd0744'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '96a33540-4d29-6243-95e1-43f9e229d3d7'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '6f765140-ac2c-2444-90f6-73dcd5983f3a'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '900e1f43-c49f-d446-93ba-a835ef2bdde3'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '4222e044-055e-854d-aa1f-dbfdfbda0cea'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'b56df048-cc47-8842-827e-3dd28254302c'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'feff3c49-581c-b342-90ea-acfa24a3f719'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f4806549-4f1b-784b-9dba-1d930c14b3fb'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '62d8bc4d-68b8-2348-8ff9-3ae4dce257e1'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '8bfa6958-cee0-af40-a343-513c5a58ab06'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'c2ad755d-bc96-7c45-9b5e-8d59c80add80'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '212af860-9af3-a748-ad0c-247378b6f783'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '7d0f8672-6c3b-0a42-aa43-83ad6b4a3e5e'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '8b6c8381-da29-8e4b-b28e-de59a4e1f208'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'd03d808c-d454-5748-a759-4baf1944f175'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'c8b05890-b97c-ab41-88f3-035b2a634474'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '28256b9e-06ea-6643-8e74-e0d19f330b78'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f0d4e2ab-181c-a84f-b0cf-b9e14368e047'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '9fc4feb5-f082-3c4a-af07-f59aa6d84c71'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'fb2f1ab6-5ea2-424e-824b-f1c7acc2498a'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '52ec0cc8-784b-1c43-9a29-1ba9bbc91682'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'f9f036ca-f79d-6343-8eb6-d4a71a689705'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '10bd51ce-b796-814f-a16b-79d8cef17467'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'c5c8d1d7-196c-0f4b-a127-5ad0597dcf14'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: 'db69aae1-17df-db4d-a600-3c1d411604bf'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] Key-Frame is not locatable anymore and will be discarded: '257e78ee-9060-2c49-87b2-8ad1c651d941'

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] World Anchor is no longer Locatable....so we have to ignore this frame as we don't know it's pose. We also deleted 36 key-frames that are no longer locatable.

Log
[MobileNeighborhoodManager::OnArFrameAvailable] CalculateSpeeds failed; speed data should not be trusted.

Log
Saving logs to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.examples.unity.helloar/files/logs.txt">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the RespCV values you included, I was able to trace your requests. The errors you were encountering here were due to an error in our storage system. The final fix was applied on 2020-04-20 20:00 UTC. Please try again now.